# Getting totals from different tables to create overall total

Tags: mysql, join, query

I currently have 2 tables `TableA` and TableB` both within the same MYSQL Database.

I am trying to find a way to take totals from both tables and add them together to give a definitive total.

The tables are used to record Trades. TableA gives the Trade info and TableB gives deposits and withdrawls.

So to get the total Profit/Loss:

`Select SUM(PL) AS PL from TableA`

Then I can get the total deposits/Withdralws as:

Select SUM(Deposits) AS Deposits, SUM(Withdraw) AS Withdrawls from TableB`

MY question is... I am looking for a way to display to current balance, essentially `SUM(PL) + (SUM(Deposits) - SUM(Withdraw) )`

I have looked at the different `join` options but cannot seem to find one that works.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thats exactly what Im after. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can simplify that a bit: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17f4f7c24452ffe7907026d039e7a371